# Memory leak ABAdressbook

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I am getting memory leaks in the following method :

```
- (void) SyncContactData
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for( int i = 0 ; i < nPeople ; i++ )
    {
        //dicContact = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i );
        NSString *str = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *strSub = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        int ii = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strSub] length];
        if(str != nil || ii == 0)
            [arrNames addObject:strSub];
        else
            [arrNames addObject:@""];

        CFTypeRef multival = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        NSArray *arrayPh = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(multival);
        if([arrayPh count] > 0)
            [arrPhone addObject:[arrayPh objectAtIndex:0]];
        else
            [arrPhone addObject:@""];

        CFRelease(multival);

    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
    CFRelease(allPeople);

}
```

Getting leaks here:

1. `NSString *str = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);`
2. `NSString *strSub = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);`
3. `NSArray *arrayPh = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(multival);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to release objects that are originally *copied* when you are done with them:

```
[str release];
[strSub release];
[arrayPh release];
```

If ARC is enabled, you might need to use `CFRelease` instead (and cast appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

So, why don't released them?

```
CFRelease(str);
CFRelease(strSub);
CFRelease(arrayPh);
```